# how to incretment parallay day month year By value 1 in sap crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

```
dateadd("d",1,{current_date});    // to add day 
dateadd("m",1,{current_date});    // to add month 
dateadd("yyyy",1,{current_date}); // to add year
```

I want to do all the things parallel in the same Formula function.  How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question does not match the minimal requirements for a question. Pleaes check how to ask good questions. What have you tried? Down voting.

Comment: Please tag your question with `crystal-reports` and the version that you are using (not every version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// add one day, one month, one year
dateadd("yyyy",1, dateadd("m",1, dateadd("d",1,{current_date})));
```